# Sending images to RoR app through an API + paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, image, paperclip

how can I make my rails app to receive images from clients through an API using paperclip plugin.
I know how to use paperclip using the ordinary form to upload the images, but i need to send images from a mac client.
thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give me a more descriptive example? I'm not sure I get what you're asking.

Comment: like sending images form an iphone app.

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't much documentation on this, so, I decided to write an article detailing how I accomplished this. It includes descriptions of the concepts so you will know how to do this on whatever client you are using. Hope this helps!

http://shawndeprey.blogspot.com/2013/05/puting-image-uploads-using-paperclip.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to upload a file (image) to a web backend right?
When you say mac-client, I'm guessing you're using Objective-C for this.

If so, you should look into [asi-http-request][1]

With this library you can upload a file like this:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest
   requestWithURL:@"http://yourserver.com/image_upload_url"];

[request setFile:fileName forKey:@"name_of_the_param"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

Should work both in iOS and MacOS

Answer (score -4):

```
<% form_for(@object,:url => upload_image_contoller_path, :html=>{:multipart => true }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label 'Image' %><br />
  <%= f.file_field  :photo %>
  <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

Also you can add model for paper clip

```
class MyImage < ActiveRecord::Base
# Paperclip
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
    :thumb=> "100x100#",
    :large =>   "400x400>" }
end
```

For more info you can go through readme file of paperclip plugin.

Comment: that was not my question sachinrathore11 :( I already know how to do that, what I'm trying to do is to be able to send images with OUT the FORM.

Comment: like sending images form an iphone app.

Comment: @SsouLlesS Please be nice. If the answer is wrong, just downvote. If you can explain what is wrong in a constructive manner, please do so. Everyone makes mistakes from time to time. As it stands, your comment is not constructive,